# Вывод значения по ключу map

Tags: java, map

У меня есть такой вот TreeMap < Class, String> и мне нужно вывести значение по ключу, если оно имеется. В findKey() пытаюсь реализовать это, но функция показывает, что такого ключа нет, хотя на деле он есть.
Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

```
public class MyCompu {

    TreeMap<CharMusic, String> tm = new TreeMap<CharMusic, String>(new MyNameComp());

    public TreeMap<CharMusic, String> base() {

        this.tm.put(new CharMusic(2018, "Alisa -- Holder"), "pop");
        this.tm.put(new CharMusic(2015, "Hola -- Dreams"), "rock");
        return tm;
}
public void findKey() {

        CharMusic charMusic1 = new CharMusic(2018, "Alisa -- Holder");
        for (Map.Entry product : base().entrySet()) {

            if (tm.containsKey(charMusic1)) {
                System.out.println(product.getKey());

            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String a[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        MyCompu myTMCompUserDefine = new MyCompu();
        myTMCompUserDefine.printKey();

    }
}
class MyNameComp implements Comparator<CharMusic> {

    @Override
    public int compare(CharMusic e1, CharMusic e2) {
        if (e1.getYear() > e2.getYear()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

class CharMusic {

    private String tittle;
    private int year;

    public CharMusic(int s, String n) {
        this.tittle = n;
        this.year = s;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (tittle == null ? 0 : tittle.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + year;
        return result;
    }

@Override
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
     if (this == o) return true;
     CharMusic other = (CharMusic) o;
     if (year != other.year)
         return false;
     return o instanceof CharMusic &&
             ((CharMusic) o).tittle.equals(tittle);

 }
}
```

Comment: `if (tittle != other.tittle)` строки сравнивайте через equals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хэш тут не при чём, это же не `HashMap`. Для выбора места хранения объекта используется переданный компаратор. Проблема в том, что компаратор не возвращает ноль для равных объектов. Решается так:

```
public int compare(CharMusic e1, CharMusic e2) {
  if (e1.year > e2.year) {
    return 1;
  } else if (e1.year == e2.year) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Ключ будет находиться. Ещё отмечу, что в `equals` у вас выполняется приведение типа до проверки `instanceof`. Лучше как-то так:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (this == o) return true;
  if (o instanceof CharMusic) {
    CharMusic cm = (CharMusic) o; 
    return cm.year == year &&
        cm.title.equals(title);
  } else return false;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень помогли!

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема заключается в том что вы переопределили метод `equals()`, к тому же неправильно, но нет переопределили метод `hashCode()`.

Map ищет значения по ключу используя метод `hashCode()`, соответственно когда она вызывает его то он выдает некорректный результат, в следствии чего ваша Map не видит нужного вам ключа.

И в методе equals вы сравниваете ссылочные типы данных через `==`, таким образом вы сравниваете их ссылки, а не содержимое. Для сравнения ссылочных типов данных стоит использовать метод `equals ()`

[Здесь](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1989-kontraktih-equals-i-hashcode-ili-kak-ono-vsje-tam) можно более подробно почитать про контакт `equals()` и `hashCode()`

Comment: Добавила hashCode(), вроде бы переопределила equals(), но ничего не поменялось..

Comment: У вас int title и String year в процессе работы программы меняются? Раз у вас не видит значения по ключу, проблема точно кроется где-то в хэшах. Либо они меняются в процессе работы либо функция неверно написана. Визуально я не вижу ошибок больше. Надо дебажить и смотреть

Comment: Не меняются. При дебаге мы не входим в условие if(tm.containsKey(charMusic1))  совсем. Согласна, что скорее всего проблема в хэшах, еще бы поймать ее)